# Why isn't echo "$0" printing the script name in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

In school I learned that "$0" would be the name of the script in bash, but when I try to print it, it actually prints -bash instead of the scriptname.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0"
```

Output: -bash

Is there something I missed, or is there another command to get the name of the script?

Comment: Use `$BASH_SOURCE`, not `$0`. `$0` is generally unreliable, as described in [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the `echo "$0"` from an interactive shell, not from a script. Maybe you put it into a script, but then sourced the script instead of calling it?

```
$ cat > 1.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0"
$ chmod u+x 1.sh
$ ./1.sh
./1.sh
```

But

```
$ echo "$0"
bash
$ . ./1.sh
bash
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try out

Answer (score 4):

Use `$BASH_SOURCE`, not `$0`, as described in [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) -- or, even better, *don't rely on being able to accurately determine your script's location at all*.

- `$0` is set by the caller, and can be any arbitrary string -- it's not guaranteed to have anything to do with the location from which the script is read.

  To demonstrate this, try running `(exec -a arbitrary-name ./your-script)`, which will execute `your-script` with `$0` set to `arbitrary-name`.
- `$0` is not updated appropriately when a script is `source`d, or when a function read from a file is executed from somewhere else; whereas `$BASH_SOURCE` *is* updated in these cases.
- A local filename *may not exist at all*: Consider the case where your script is run with `ssh remotehost 'bash -s' <./scriptname`: There is no local filename that corresponds with your script's source.